# I am tracing code through an existing project, what does this piece do?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to learn laravel by stepping through this existing project I was given, and I am trying figure our what this line of code does:

`$location = Location::find($location_id);`

Specifically the `Location::find` portion. I ran into a piece that has `Config::get` and I learned that it calls the config folder. But I don't have a Location folder, so what format is `Location::find(__)`? How can I find where it is pointing to so I can trace the code?

Thanks!

Comment: A good IDE will have a go to declaration feature

Comment: Might I suggest [reading the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) method gets an object by its primary key.

> In addition to retrieving all of the records for a given table, you may also retrieve single records using `find` or `first`. Instead of returning a collection of models, these methods return a single model instance

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: So does this mean it is accessing the database?

Comment: Yes, it gets the data from DB